# programmatically access UIViewController identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I have a base `UIViewController` I inherit from for some basic content in my app using storyboards.

I instantiate it like this:

```
BasicContentViewController *targetController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ColorCouture"];
        [self.navigationController pushFadeViewController:targetController];
```

OR

```
 BasicContentViewController *targetController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Hospitality"];
        [self.navigationController pushFadeViewController:targetController];
```

Is there a way for me to check the Identifier I used to instantiate the `UIViewControllers`?

I want to make sure I am not pushing more than 1 of each of these controller onto my `UIViewController` stack

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You do have the identifiers, since you use them to instantiate your view controllers. What exactly are do you want to check?

Comment: It [appears](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708660/programmatically-get-a-storyboard-id) the answer is no.

Comment: actually, if you read down further you can use restorationId, which works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question solves my problem for me:

[Programmatically get a Storyboard ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708660/programmatically-get-a-storyboard-id)

I am just using the restorationId instead, works perfectly.