# How to know the current storyboard name in xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

How can I put in a string variable the name of the current storyboard
Ive got this for objective-c

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = self.storyboard;
NSString * storyboardName = [storyboard valueForKey:@"name"];
```

but I have to pass it to Xamarin iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xamarin.iOS`:

```
var storyBoard = this.Storyboard;
var storyBoardName = storyBoard.ValueForKey(new NSString ("name"));
```

Comment: got a new error NSString does not exist in the current context
Im using a Simple View App

Comment: @RodrigoChavarria `NSString` is in the `Foundation` namespace, add a `using Foundation;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this in the storyboard's custom ViewController:

`NSString storyboardId = (NSString) ValueForKey(new NSString("storyboardIdentifier"));`

To get just the string, you can simply use `storyboardId.ToString()` (NSString function), though NSString mostly behaves the same way as string, e.g. in Dictionaries.

converted to C# from Swift from this answer:
[Programmatically get a Storyboard ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708660/programmatically-get-a-storyboard-id)